# Rails Postgres many to many relationship with custom foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fact table, `clients` with a bunch of businesses:

```
  bus_id, sales,  date  
    1,    $986,  1/1/2016  
    1,    $543,  1/2/2016  
    2,    $921,  1/1/2016  
    2,    $345,  1/2/2016
```

I want to create a table `opportunities`

```
  bus_id,  opportunity  
     1,     "Upsell"  
     1,    "Upsell More"
```

How do I create the `opportunities` table so that I could display the opportunities per `bus_id`?

Comment: You want to do a many to many relation with `clients` table and `opportunities` table?

Comment: yes, on the bus_id field

Comment: Only the `primary key` of one table can be used as a `foreign key` of another table. So I guess you have to take a different approach for what you want to achieve. Tell us what exactly you want to do.

Comment: May I ask do you have a `businesses` table?

Comment: Edited question. I just want to show the opportunities per bus_id in a view. So, bus_id 1 would show the "Upsell" and "Upsell More" rows.

Comment: I don't have a businesses table, the business names are actually stored in the fact table.. I need a quick way to connect 2 tables without trying to build out a bunch of extra dimension tables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the migration command:

`bin/rails g model opportunity custom_foreign_bus_id:integer:index description`

**businesses.rb**

```
has_many :opportunities, foreign_key: :custom_foreign_bus_id
```

**opportunity.rb**

```
belongs_to :business, foreign_key: :custom_foreign_bus_id
```

Then to get the Business Opportunities:

`Business.find(1).opportunities`

*or simply:*

`Opportunity.where(custom_foreign_bus_id: 1)`

**To do a many-to-many you need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association or a join model, is that what you really want?**

[2.8 Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: So, in your solution, the :custom_foreign_bus_id isn't a primary key in any table? And that is ok?

Comment: `:custom_foreign_bus_id` lives on the **opportunity.rb** model, it does not exist anywhere else. Declaring `..., foreign_key: :custom_foreign_bus_id` will tell rails how to associate that custom foreign_key to the real primary key name.

Comment: In your opinion, it is also ok to switch the has_many and belongs_to to has_and_belongs to many as ideally this would be a many to many relationship?

Comment: You can do that, you would just need to create another table to do so and do some slightly different settings. If you make another question I'll go into detail on how that works, just link me to it in the comments here.

Comment: Sounds good @blnc   Here is the habtm question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953235/rails-pg-habtm-relationship