# Rails PG HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fact table, clients with a bunch of businesses:

```
  bus_id, sales,  date  
    1,    $986,  1/1/2016  
    1,    $543,  1/2/2016  
    2,    $921,  1/1/2016  
    2,    $345,  1/2/2016
```

I want to create a table opportunities

```
  bus_id,  opportunity  
     1,     "Upsell"  
     1,    "Upsell More"
```

How do I create the opportunities table with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between the two so that they are linked on the bus_id foreign key?

Comment: Are you asking about the associations or the migrations or both?

Comment: If the migrations are just the column names above and data types, then the associations. My biggest concern is that bus_id is not a PK in either table?

Comment: explain the use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a join model for them:

```
bin/rails g migration create_businesses_opportunities
```

Now, go to the migration file and make sure it looks like this:

```
class CreateBusinessesOpportunities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :businesses_opportunities do |t|
      t.belongs_to :opportunity, index: true
      t.belongs_to :business, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

**models/business.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :opportunities
```

**models/opportunity.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses
```

What this will do is add a 'dynamic' attribute to each model that will store the ids into an array.

Example:

```
#To have an opportunity belong to multiple businesses, say IDs 1, 2, and 3
@opp = Opportunity.find(1)
@opp.update_attribute :business_ids, [1,2,3]
@opp.businesses
    # => will now show the three businesses

#The same works for associating a business to multiple opportunities, just the other way around
@busn = Business.find(1)
@busn.update_attribute :opportunity_ids, [1,2,3]
@busn.opportunities
    # => will now show the three opportunities
```